# Making elements roll off and another roll in by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two elements and I want element1 to roll off and element2 will appear. Afterwhich when the button is clicked again, element2 rolls away to reveal element1 using CSS and/or Javascript.

Please use sample contents for these as I have no Html element sample to upload. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is create a class with rolling animation style with the help of `transform:translate(x, y) rotate(xdeg);` and toggle the class in both element1 and element2 with the help of Jquery on click event.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('.element1').toggleClass('roll-off');
    $('.element2').toggleClass('roll-off');
});
```

Comment: Let me try this out Kasimali. Thanks a lot